# Concatenating lists in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and would like to take this

```
K=[['d','o','o','r'], ['s','t','o','p']]
```

to print:

```
door, stop
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

`', '.join(''.join(x) for x in K)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.join()` and `map()`:

```
In [26]: K=[['d','o','o','r'], ['s','t','o','p']]

In [27]: ", ".join(map("".join,K))
Out[27]: 'door, stop'
```

> S.join(iterable) -> string
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
>   iterable.  The separator between elements is S.